# GAN measurement - FID score

Tags: pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

I have two GANs and I want to compare their results using FID (Fréchet Inception Distance).
I have trianed the networks with the same dataset of frogs images, and by looking at the results (the generated images) one network yields better results but it's FID score is higher.
I computed the FID score between the original dataset and the generated images of each network.

I have read that lower FID values mean better image quality and diversity,
which is not consistent with the results I have seen.

Is there an explanation for that?

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.06991v3.pdf. It clearly describes the problem of FID scores. However, the FID scores are also dependant on the number of samples. If you are using fewer samples to estimate it then the outcomes are not consistent.